# Linq2SQL sortorder

Tags: linq-to-sql, sql-order-by

i need to order some data in the following way

```
DTO{
  id //nullable
  name // not nullable
}

demodata
entry1: Null / "TopItem"
entry2: 1    / "Numer1"
entry2: 3    / "Numer3"
entry2: 2    / "Numer2"
```

Say i need to have the item with id null on top and all other entries sorted by the column name

can this be done with LINQ2SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
from dto in context.DTO
orderby !dto.id.HasValue, dto.name
select dto
```